# Objective C get version for specified app

Tags: objective-c, macos

How can I get app version (or more info) for an input like `/Applications/Firefox.app` in Objective C?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Informations about an app are located in the Info.plist file.

For example, `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Info.plist`.

You can parse it in a `NSDictionary`.

For the app version, the key is `CFBundleShortVersionString`.